# Is there an HTML tag that does nothing, so I can use it as a flag?

Tags: html, dom

Full context, because I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for:

I am working on web software, and I have various mail templates that get sent. The templates are just HTML files. I'm planning to implement a text editor so that my clients can edit these mail templates. However, there are certain 'chunks' for the files that I don't want them to be able to edit, so I was thinking of putting 'flags' of some kind into the html so that I can detect them programmatically and make the blocks un-editable in the UI.

I was envisioning something like this:

```
<p>
  lots of text here
</p>
<blank-tag-here-that-wont-display-or-do-anything>
<p>
  important un-editable text here
</p>
<blank-tag-here-that-wont-display-or-do-anything>
<p>
  other text here
</p>
```

Is there such a tag? Or something else I'm not considering? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can’t you use `id`? Also you didn’t end your custom tag. Don’t want to risk downvotes because of https://xkcd.com/1144/

Comment: Your question is confusing - could you elaborate on what you intend `<blank-tag-here-that-wont-display-or-do-anything>` to be doing? Or what purpose it would serve?

Comment: Maybe I am getting this wrong, but can't you add a custom attribute like `data-noneditable` to the `<p>` tag. Easier than adding random HTML tags. Why need a tag for this.

Comment: I think using 'id' is probably best...I can just string search for <span id="uneditable"> and remove that chunk from the string. Don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using your context then parse the html tags to find the  tag and make the whole block visible='false' to the html editor, this way it will not show in the editor but if the html editor has the html view capability then the user will be able to modify the tag via the html viewer.